How do I transform `s` into a waiting key combo in Neovim?
By default, in Neovim, the s binding immediately enters insert mode after deleteting the character under the cursor.
I want to change this behaviour. I want that s behaves like g, in that it waits forever for another keypress, so that I can insert whatever combo I'd like.
Note: I'm using <leader> for another purpouses.
This is currently working in my init.lua:
vim.keymap.set("n", "sh", "<C-w><C-h>", { desc = "Move focus to the left window" })
vim.keymap.set("n", "sl", "<C-w><C-l>", { desc = "Move focus to the right window" })
vim.keymap.set("n", "sj", "<C-w><C-j>", { desc = "Move focus to the lower window" })
vim.keymap.set("n", "sk", "<C-w><C-k>", { desc = "Move focus to the upper window" })
vim.keymap.set("n", "sx", "<C-w>s", { desc = "create horizontal partition" })
vim.keymap.set("n", "sy", "<C-w>v", { desc = "create vertical partition" })

but if I don't type the combo fast enough, after typing s, it enters insert mode as per the default behavior thus jeopardizing my intentions.

If the problem is timing, you might want to check the timeout settings that affect mappings.

Do you still have something open in your question ? How can we help you further ?Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solutions using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons.  It allow the question to rest :-)

I would add:
vim.keymap.set("n", "s", "<Nop>", { desc = "do nothing" })

